# jQuery window resize

Tags: javascript, resize

I have piece of javascript code, which **should process when the browser window is resized**.

```
resize.style.marginRight=(resize.offsetWidth-$(this)[0].offsetWidth)+'px'
```

Tryed this stuff (doesn't work):

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
resize.style.marginRight=(resize.offsetWidth-$(this)[0].offsetWidth)+'px'
}
```

**Full code** available - http://jsbin.com/adelu3/2/ (see page source)

Html (generated by the script):

```
<div class="resizable-textarea">
    <span>
        <textarea class="resizable processed" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
        <div class="resize"></div>
    </span>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: @vsync - It gives right margin-right on load, but doesn't change when browser window is resized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this)[0].offsetWidth
```

`offsetWidth` is a property of elements. In the callback code of `window.onresize`, `this` is a `Window`, which doesn't have an offsetWidth.

What is `this` supposed to be? (The `onresize` event is not present in the linked code.) If you want to read the window width, use `$(window).width()`.

If you want to read the width of some other (ancestor?) element that you had as `this` in the enclosing scope, you must either find that element by looking up from the `resize` element, or retain a reference to the other element in a closure, eg.:

```
var that= this;
$(window).resize(function() {
    resize.style.marginRight= resize.offsetWidth-that.offsetWidth+'px'
});
```

(nb. `$(this)[0]` does precisely nothing.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough knowlegde in javascript. Can you give a full code?

Comment: This doesn't work - $(window).width(function() {
resize.style.marginRight=(resize.offsetWidth-$(this)[0].offsetWidth)+'px')
});

Comment: And this too - $(window).width(resize.style.marginRight=(resize.offsetWidth-$(this)[0].offsetWidth)+'px');

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work everytime, sometimes gives a negative margin.

Comment: So, here is a html: <div class="resizable-textarea"><span><textarea class="resizable processed" cols="" rows=""></textarea><div class="resize"></div></span></div>

Comment: Function changes Margin-right for div.resize. Its >better< to change Width instead. It could take the Width from textarea.resizable and give it to div.resize

Comment: OK, so you could use `$(resize).closest('div').width()` to get the width of the `resizable-textarea` element from the textarea, if that's what you want. Or store a reference to it in `that`, as above. `this` is a special variable that corresponds to the object a function was called on, so you can't get the outer function's `this` from the nested function directly.

Answer (score 0):

Made myself.

This is a mixed solution, it shares @bobince's code and my own.

```
var tarea= this;
function resize_width(){ resize.style.width= tarea.offsetWidth+'px'}
resize_width();
$(window).resize(function() {resize_width()});
```